# Working with JavaFX Choicebox and if statements

Tags: javafx

Here is the situation: I have a choicebox with 12 items. I would like to know how do I go about implementing the "if" statement, so if clicking the first item some code gets executed and if the second item gets clicked some other code gets executed. Here is what I have done so far:

```
    //THE DROPDOWN 
    ChoiceBox<String> Choice = new ChoiceBox<>();
    Choice.getItems().addAll("C","Db","D","Eb","E","F","Gb","G","Ab","A","Bb","B");
    Choice.setValue("C");
    //Reacting acording to the selected item 
    Choice.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((V, oldValue, newValue) -> lbl.setText(newValue));
```

Right now, whatever item gets clicked will be set to the lbl control

But as said before I'd like to have an if statement implemented ...Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

Well, the semantics of Lambda allow you to add more than one statement.
Use braces:

```
Choice.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((V, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    if(someTest)
        ...
    else
        ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. It solved half of the  problem. The thing now is the test. I need it to be something like: if (newValue == " C") ... Where "C" is one of the items in the Choicebox.

Comment: Just write `if ("C".equals(newValue)) ...`, Ricardo, I don't quite see what your issue is.  If you want to evaluate on a bunch of different items, you can use a large switch statement. You could also listen to [valueProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ChoiceBox.html#valueProperty--), rather than selectedItemProperty(), though that makes no difference.